# Acro Package: Write abbreviation between long form

Tags: acronyms, acro

I am using the ACRO-package in my masterthesis. Is there a way to tell ACRO to put the abbrevation between a certain word of the long form, when using `\acf`?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{hvac}{short = HVAC, long = heating, ventilating and air conditioning system}

\begin{document}
Full Acronym: \acf{hvac}. 
\end{document}
```

I want it to be **heating, ventilating and air conditioning (HVAC) system**

instead of

**heating, ventilating and air conditioning system (HVAC)**

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: You may consider removing the word 'system' from the long form and use `\acf{hvac} system` in the main text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the first style should contain the acronym definition inside it while having conventional long and short forms I think this is a case for nested acronym definitions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{HVAC}{
  short = HVAC,
  long = {heating, ventilating and air conditioning},
}
\DeclareAcronym{hvac}{
  short = HVAC,
  long = \ac{HVAC} system,
  first-style = long
}

\begin{document}
Full Acronym: \acf{hvac}. 
\end{document}
```

By setting the `first-style` of the outer acronym `hvac` to `long` we always see `\ac{HVAC} system` for first/long or `\ac{HVAC}` for short.  Assuming the inner `HVAC` acronym is never used independently this gives a first appearance of `heating, ventilating and air conditioning (HVAC) system`, subsequent first/long appearances of `HVAC system`, and short appearances of `HVAC`.

Depending exactly what is wanted you may wish to put `long = \acf{HVAC} system`, or use some additional conditionals.

One can achieve a similar effect by placing conditionals in a single acronym

```
\DeclareAcronym{hvac}{
  short = HVAC,
  long = {heating, ventilating and air conditioning\acroiffirstT{\acspace(HVAC)} system},
  first-style=long,
}
```

but this is less resilient to changes in style and utilisation of [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro)'s other features.

Comment: Thank you very much :)